# OpenGL Keyboard Events not working

Tags: opengl, keyboard

I have the following snippet:

```
float z, yrot = 0, xrot = 0;
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;

void display()                                                  /* 2. */
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         /* 3. */

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode   (GL_MODELVIEW);
glTranslatef(x, y, -0.5);
glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, -1);
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glutWireTeapot(0.2);


glutSwapBuffers();                                          /* 4. */
}

void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

     float yrotrad = (yrot / (180 * 3.141592654f));
     float xrotrad = (xrot / (180 * 3.141592654f));

     switch (key)
     {

         case 'w':

            x += (float)(sin(yrotrad));
            z -= (float)(cos(yrotrad)) ;
            y -= (float)(sin(xrotrad));
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
     }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)                                 /* 5. */
{
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

What is supposed to happen when I press the <kbd>w</kbd> key is that it's supposed to tilt the camera. But when I press <kbd>w</kbd>, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try 'e', locales problem maybe

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` and `y` parameters are shadowing the globals:

```
void keyPressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
```

So the increment of those is not doing what you think it does. Turn up your compiler warnings -- you'll probably see some about losing precision.

Ironically, it works correctly for `z` but you don't seem to be using it anywhere in your rendering code.

(Aside: You may also want to look into [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/). It's quite similar to GLUT and as easy to get started with, but better in every respect.)